# html, jquery, css - catalog of goods with sliding table of types (modifications)

Tags: jquery, css, html

Need help:
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/1/
How to make that goods didn't move down?

When use:

```
float:left;
```

its moving

Sorry for my bad english

**Added 1:**
If clicking on good, table must be show in next row, but other good from this row must be on that place where they were. Maket is rubber and goods must get places in some rows.

**Added 2:**
"Good" is "Product"

**Added 3:**
I trying to experement and it want to view like: http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/8/

```
display: inline-block;
```

**Finish:**
I decided this issue:
Thanks to prerit ahuja for idea of div-blocks. I used for

```
display: inline-block;
```

in div ".models" and added div to ".types" for using

```
display: inline-block;
```

too.

Thanks for all. Example see in jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/9/ (I can't use third "link" because reputation less 10)

Comment: You mean it should always be in one row?

Comment: We understand that English is not your first language. However, you will need someone to help you make your message understood. You aren't giving enough information for us to know what your problem is and what you want to do.

Comment: 140 000 th question under css tag :) just the mileage of my car ... don't mind it

Comment: If clicking on good, table must be show in next row, but other good from this row must be on that place where they were.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/3/ Hard to tell what you're asking\

Comment: why would you do that, i mean its a very good solution if they break into the next row if resizing and co :)

Comment: Juan Mendes, no. Maket is rubber. Goods must get places in some rows.

Comment: It's unclear which part of the code you're referring to. Please be more detailed listings steps to reproduce the problem along with actual/expected behavior

Comment: @user2510126 Sorry, it's hard to tell what you mean... "Maket is rubber" doesn't mean anything to me... What is a good? I'm afraid you have to improve the English in the question

Comment: "Good" is means "Product"

Comment: I trying to experement and it want to view like: http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/8/

Answer (score -1):

your layout is breaking due to table structure, better to create layout in div

e.g

```
<div>
<div><img src="product image"/></div>
<div>Description</div>
</div>
```

and in jquery instead of using $.after use $.append it will append the details in main div only.

Hi, I have updates your structure to use, please reffer http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/5/

```
<div class="models">
<a href="?10257" class="mod" id="10257">
<table >
<tr>
<td class="image"><img src="10257.jpg"></td></tr><tr><td class="desc"><b><span class="name">Товар 1</span></b><br><span class="years">2012.10 – Данный момент</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</a>
</div>
```

and add css

```
.models table
{
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: -1 Please explain how the table layout breaks it, right now this doesn't look like mucj of an answer

Comment: I m not saying its not possible in table , i m just suggesting that better to use div structure for such layouts.

Comment: refer this , i have updated your little bit structure http://jsfiddle.net/JQaLs/5/

Comment: Like this, but table width must be = ".models" width and next row slide down

Comment: Please explain more your problem